# Unknown Property 'xxx' Found in Emotion Next/JS React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, emotion

I'm having a problem with the code recognizing the css for @emotion/react and I am not sure how to remove this error in order to get it to successfully compile the build. I would appreciate any help you could provide on how to address this error. Thank you.

Yarn Build fails due to:

```
26:17  Error: Unknown property 'css' found  react/no-unknown-property
```

I am not sure how to get this to work. Is there a better way to rewrite this?

```
          <div
            key={`${config.stakePoolData.pubkey.toString()}`}
            className="flex w-full cursor-pointer gap-4 border-b border-border px-8 py-4 md:flex-row"
            css={css`
              &:hover {
                background: ${config.stakePoolMetadata?.colors?.primary &&
                transparentize( 0.9, config.stakePoolMetadata.colors?.primary
                )};
              }
            `}
            onClick={() => {
              router.push(
                `/${
                  config.stakePoolMetadata?.name ??
                  config.stakePoolData.pubkey.toString()
                }${location.search}`
              )
            }}
            >
```

Below is more of the code for reference:

```
 import { shortPubKey } from '@cardinal/common'
 import { css } from '@emotion/react'
 import { ButtonSmall } from 'common/ButtonSmall'
 import type { StakePool } from 'hooks/useAllStakePools'
 import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
 import { transparentize } from 'polished'

 export const CollectionsList = ({ configs }: { configs?: StakePool[] }) => {
  const router = useRouter()
   return (
    <div className="w-full overflow-x-scroll overflow-y-scroll rounded-xl border border- 
     border p-4">
     <div className="flex w-full min-w-fit flex-col">
      <div className="flex w-full gap-4 rounded-xl bg-dark-4 px-8 py-2">
       <div className="flex-1">Image</div>
        <div className="flex-[2]">Collection</div>
         <div className="flex-[2] justify-end text-right"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col">
         {!configs ? (
         <></>
         ) : (          
         [...configs].map((config) => (              
         <div
            key={`${config.stakePoolData.pubkey.toString()}`}
            className="flex w-full cursor-pointer gap-4 border-b border-border px-8 py-4 md:flex-row"
            css={css`
              &:hover {
                background: ${config.stakePoolMetadata?.colors?.primary &&
                transparentize( 0.9, config.stakePoolMetadata.colors?.primary
                )};
              }
            `}
            onClick={() => {
              router.push(
                `/${
                  config.stakePoolMetadata?.name ??
                  config.stakePoolData.pubkey.toString()
                }${location.search}`
              )
            }}
            >              
            <div className="min-w-fit flex-1">
              <div className="flex items-center gap-5 md:flex-row">
                {config.stakePoolMetadata?.imageUrl ? (
                  <img
                    className={`h-full max-h-[50px] max-w-[150px] rounded-xl ${
                      config.stakePoolMetadata.contrastHomepageBkg &&
                      `bg-white bg-opacity-20 p-2`
                    } ${config.stakePoolMetadata?.logoPadding && 'p-3'}`}
                    src={config.stakePoolMetadata?.imageUrl}
                    alt={
                      config.stakePoolMetadata?.name ??
                      config.stakePoolData.pubkey.toString()
                    }
                  />                                            
                ) : (
                  <div className="flex h-[50px] w-[50px] items-center justify-center rounded-full text-lg text-white text-opacity-40">
                    <img
                      className={`h-full max-h-[40px] max-w-[150px] rounded-xl`}
                      src={'/cardinal-crosshair.svg'}
                      alt={config.stakePoolData.pubkey.toString()}
                    />
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-[2] items-center">
              {config.stakePoolMetadata?.displayName ??
                shortPubKey(config.stakePoolData.pubkey.toString())}
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-[2] justify-end">
              <ButtonSmall>View</ButtonSmall>
            </div>
          </div>
         ))
        )}
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  )
 }
```

Comment: DOM elements don't have a `css` property. Do you mean `style`?

Comment: It's using emotion react which does use the css property instead of style

Comment: Then I guess you are missing `import { jsx } from '@emotion/react'`?  https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion#quick-start

Comment: Or maybe you have to update your eslint rules: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unknown-property.md#rule-options

Answer (score 3):

Without more information, this could be occurring due to a variety of reasons. I would highly recommend going over the [official Emotion install docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/install) to double check you haven't missed anything.

I'll attempt to provide a few suggestions to help you out.

---

1. First, I would confirm you have ran `yarn add @emotion/react` from the `root` directory of your project.

2. If you have setup your project manually (like with [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)), make sure to use [@emotion/babel-plugin](https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/babel-plugin). You can install it with `yarn add --dev @emotion/babel-plugin`. Simply add `@emotion` to your `.babelrc` file like so:

   ```
   {
     "plugins": ["@emotion"]
   }
   ```

   Also note, if you are using Babel's env option emotion must also be first for each environment:

   ```
   {
     "env": {
       "production": {
         "plugins": ["@emotion", ...otherBabelPlugins]
       }
     },
     "plugins": ["@emotion"]
   }
   ```

3. Next, I would check that [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) has been configured correctly. Normally, the [react/no-unknown-property](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unknown-property.md) rule from [eslint-plugin-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react) will produce an error if the `css` prop is passed to a DOM element. As mentioned in the [official Emotion docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/eslint-plugin-react), This violation of the rule can be safely ignored because `@emotion/react` intercepts the `css` prop before it is applied to the DOM element.

   Apply the rule like so to your [ESLint configuration file](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files) like so:

   ```
   {
     "rules": {
       "react/no-unknown-property": ["error", { "ignore": ["css"] }]
     }
   }
   ```

4. Finally, in case you are using TypeScript, you'll need to add the type declaration. I'm not sure which [CSS-in-JSS](https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.10.0) framework you are using, so I will document how to do this for [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) and [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction).

   Create a type declaration file called `style.d.ts` at either the `root` or somewhere in the `src` directory.

   For `styled-components`:

   ```
   import { CSSProp } from "styled-components";

   interface DefaultTheme {}

   declare module "react" {
      interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends DOMAttributes<T> {
        css?: CSSProp<DefaultTheme>;
      }
    }
   ```

   For `emotion`:

   ```
   import type { SerializedStyles } from "@emotion/serialize";
   import type { DOMAttributes } from "react";

   declare module "react" {
       interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends DOMAttributes<T> {
           css?: SerializedStyles;
       }
   }
   ```

   In your `tsconfig.json` file, make sure to include the newly created file:

   ```
   "include": [
       "other.d.ts",
       "src/another.d.ts",
       "style.d.ts",
   ]
   ```

5. If all else fails, have a read of the official Emotion [css prop docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop) to see if you might have missed anything.

Hopefully this helps you and any future devs who might be stuck with this!

Comment: I didn't use ChatGPT to write this answer...